# Сохранение изображений в android приложении

Tags: java, android, picasso

Надо сохранить либо на памяти телефона, либо на SD карте шесть изображений. Они загружаются из интернета. Для загрузки использую Picasso. Пытаюсь через Target создать новый файл изображения, а в дальнейшем вывести его. Вот код:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(image_ar.get(0)).into(new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        Log.e("tag", "Picasso > onBitmapLoaded");
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/name.jpg"); //путь к изображению 
        FileOutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("file:///" + file.getPath()).into(image.get(0));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        Log.e("tag", "Picasso > onBitmapFailed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        Log.e("tag", "Picasso > onPrepareLoad");
    }
});
```

Но в результате не получаю ничего.

Comment: У вас в коде по событию загрузки изображения в ImageView загружается какой-то файл. Записи в файл в коде нигде нет. И загруженная из интернета картинка нигде не используется

Comment: А как это исправить можете подсказать? На примере если можно, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Согласно выдаче гугла на запрос

> [android write bitmap to file](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20write%20bitmap%20to%20file)

записать `Bitmap` в файл можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673014/3212712):

```
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
    // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

2. Далее этот файл можно отобразить чрез `Picasso` так:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()) 
.load("file:///" + filePath) 
.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) 
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: Тоже самое, код в вопросе исправил

Comment: @Jonny, у вас файл создался с картинкой? Может вы разрешения на запись не указали?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
Это прописано. Файл приложение как бы видит, но картинка сама не отображается. Просто по-умолчанию там уже есть изображение, но в ImageView не выводится ничего следовательно картинка существует, просто не отображается, либо она не загружается в файл.

Comment: @Jonny, попробуйте добавить ещё и на чтение разрешение. Также проверьте записалась ли таки картинка в файл

Comment: Точно, спасибо, всё работает.))